# xterm.js : fitAddon.fit() throws ERROR Error: This API only accepts integers

Tags: javascript, angular, xtermjs

Scenario : on button click, I hit window.open to open new tab in browser where I used the xterm.js inside the component in angular.

Problem : ERROR Error: This API only accepts integers

code :

```
ngOnInit() { 
this.terminal = new Terminal(this.baseTerminalOptions)
this.terminal?.loadAddon(this.fitAddon);
}

ngAfterViewInint() {
this.terminal?.open(this.terminalWrapper.nativeElement);
    this.fitAddon?.fit(); // problem line in console
    this.terminal.writeln('enter something in web-ssh-shell \n \r');
}
```

```
Angular 14
"xterm": "4.4.0",
"xterm-addon-fit": "0.3.0"
```

expecting it to render the terminal without any error.

Comment: Most likely an error in your `this.baseTerminalOptions` mixing integer only options with something else.

Comment: @jerch Can you share or refer me the default / values of baseTerminalOptions? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/fb2c39cb5748e071e0a1ed49824590aafd45e65e/src/common/services/OptionsService.ts#L12 - thats for current version (your version is quite outdated).